# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x \log \left(\frac{a^2+2 a x \cos (t)+x^2}{a^2-2 a x \cos (t)+x^2}\right)}{b^2+x^2} \ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

G&R 4.296 states that
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x \log \left(\frac{a^2+2 a x \cos (t)+x^2}{a^2-2 a x \cos (t)+x^2}\right)}{b^2+x^2} \, dx=\frac{\pi\  \text{arctan} \left(\left(a^2-b^2\right) \cos (t)\right)}{\left(a^2+b^2\right) \sin (t)+2 a b}-\pi  t+\frac{\pi ^2}{2},a,b>0,0<t<\pi$$

How can we prove this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Other than DUIS, the first things I would try are to try to abuse the symmetries in the logarithm and map $x \mapsto 1/x$ and/or use partial fractions (after which we could either probably get away with a Keyhole contour using complex analysis else *maybe* use a studied generalization or Frullani's Theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the integral into a double integral in the following way:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\log\left(\frac{x^2+2ax\cos t +a^2}{x^2 - 2ax\cos t + a^2} \right)}{x^2 + b^2}dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \frac{2ax^2}{x^2+b^2} \frac{1}{x^2 + 2axy + a^2}dydx$$
Partial fraction decomposition yields:
$$\int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\left(\frac{2a^3(a^2-b^2) + 4a^3b^2y^2}{(x+ay)^2+a^2(1-y^2)} - \frac{2a^2b^2y(2x+2ay)}{x^2+2ayx+a^2} \right)$$
$$  + \frac{1}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\left( \frac{2a^2b^2y(2x)}{x^2+b^2} - \frac{2ab^2(a^2-b^2)}{x^2+b^2}\right) dxdy$$
$$=\int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \frac{1}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\left(\frac{2a^3(a^2-b^2) + 4a^3b^2y^2}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+ay}{a\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)\right)$$
$$ + \frac{2a^2b^2y}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\log\left(\frac{x^2+b^2}{x^2+2ayx+a^2}\right) -\frac{2ab(a^2-b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) \Biggr|_0^\infty dy$$
$$= \int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \frac{2a^2(a^2-b^2+2b^2y^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\frac{\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy$$ $$+ \int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t}\frac{2a^2b^2y}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\log\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} \right) + \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{2ab(b^2-a^2)}{(b^2-a^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2} dy$$
The last two integrals are easy enough to do, the log integral is odd so it cancels, then the third integral is
$$\frac{\pi }{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2aby}{b^2-a^2} \right) \Biggr |_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} = \pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2ab\cos t}{b^2-a^2} \right)$$
Turning our attention back to the first, we can rewrite it in the following way:
$$= \int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \left(1 + \frac{a^4-b^4}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\right)\frac{\cos^{-1}(y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy $$
$$= \int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \left(1 + \frac{a^4-b^4}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\right)\frac{\cos^{-1}(y)-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy $$
$$= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\cos t}^{\cos t} \left(1 + \frac{a^4-b^4}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2y^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy $$
because $\cos^{-1}y - \frac{\pi}{2}$ is an odd function. The +1 integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi t$. Then continuing further
$$ = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_t^{\pi-t} \frac{a^4-b^4}{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2\cos^2 \theta} d\theta =  \frac{\pi}{2}\int_t^{\pi-t} \frac{(a^4-b^4)\sec^2\theta}{(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2\tan^2 \theta} d\theta$$
$$ = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_t^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(a^4-b^4)\sec^2\theta}{(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2\tan^2 \theta} d\theta +  \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi-t} \frac{(a^4-b^4)\sec^2\theta}{(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2\tan^2 \theta} d\theta$$
 $$ = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\tan t}^{\infty} \frac{(a^4-b^4)}{(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2z^2} dz + \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{-\tan t} \frac{(a^4-b^4)}{(a^2+b^2)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2z^2} dz $$
$$ = \frac{\pi^2}{2} - \pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(a^2-b^2)\tan t}{(a^2+b^2)} \right) = \pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\cot t}{(a^2-b^2)} \right) $$
Adding up the answers from all of our parts, we get
$$\pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\cot t}{a^2-b^2} \right) - \pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2ab\cos t}{a^2-b^2} \right) + \frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi t$$
Then using the fact that $\tan^{-1}a + \tan^{-1}b = \tan^{-1}\frac{a+b}{1-ab}$ we get
$$\pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos t}{(a^2+b^2)\sin t + 2ab}\right)-\pi t+ \frac{\pi^2}{2}$$
which is not quite the formula you wrote but it's too close for me to believe it is a coincidence, given all the room for error in this calculation.